# Webpack issues when setting up Sass and CSS modules in React

Tags: webpack, sass, css-modules

My app doesn't compile and when I try an npm install i see this:

```
npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2 requires a peer of webpack@^3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

However, this only started to happen when I added this plugin to my webpack.config.dev.js:

```
new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'styles.css', allChunks: true }),
```

and when I try to run my app i get the following:

> /Users/johnnynolan/Repos/clark-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Chunk.js:824
>                   throw new Error(
>                   ^
>
> Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by
>   instanceof Entrypoint instead
>       at Chunk.get (/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/clark-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Chunk.js:824:9)
>       at /Users/johnnynolan/Repos/clark-app/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:176:48
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at /Users/johnnynolan/Repos/clark-app/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:171:18
>       at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/clark-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10),
>   :7:1)
>       at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/clark-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
>       at Compilation.seal (/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/clark-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1214:27)
>       at hooks.make.callAsync.err (/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/clark-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:547:17)
>       at _done (eval at create (/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/clark-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10),
>   :11:1)
>       at _err1 (eval at create (/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/clark-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10),
>   :34:22)

Comment: What version of webpack are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`ExtractTextPlugin` is deprecated.
Instead of that, you could use `style-loader`, `css-loader` and `postcss-loader` by adding below code to your webpack and by installing required packages.

```js
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: [{
      loader: 'style-loader' // creates style nodes from JS strings
    },
    {
      loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
      options: {
        importLoaders: 1,
        modules: true,
        localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]"
      },
    },
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        modules: true,
        localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]"
      } // compiles Sass to CSS
    },
    {
      loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
      options: {
        ident: 'postcss',
        plugins: () => [
          require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
          autoprefixer({
            browsers: [
              '>1%',
              'last 4 versions',
              'Firefox ESR',
              'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
            ],
            flexbox: 'no-2009',
          }),
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
},
```